# Java sorting collection vs DB fetch collection

Tags: java, string, hibernate, sorting

I have a problem where i try to sort a list of objects in java. I am getting a different result when the list of objects is created manually or fetch from the Database.

This is the object :

```
public class CompanyRoleProperties implements Serializable {

     private String officeName;

    public CompanyRoleProperties() {
        super();
    }

    public CompanyRoleProperties(String officeName) {
        super();
        this.officeName = officeName;
    }

    public static SQLQuery createQuery(final Session session, final StringBuilder query) {
        final SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query.toString());

         sqlQuery.addScalar("officeName", StandardBasicTypes.STRING);
         sqlQuery.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(CompanyRoleProperties.class));
        return sqlQuery;
    }

.... 
}
```

I have a function that retrieve data from the Database and create a list of those objects :

```
public List<CompanyRoleProperties> getServiceProviders() {

    final StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder(); 
    query.append("select distinct * from getCompanyRoleProperties()");
    query.append(" ORDER BY startDate DESC , endDate DESC ");
    this.log.info(query.toString());

    return CompanyRoleProperties.createQuery(this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession(), query).list();

}
```

i have this generic comparator i used for the sorting:

```
public class GenericComparator<T extends Object> implements Comparator<T> {
    private SortOrder   sortType    = null;
    private String      sortField   = null;

    public GenericComparator(String sortField, SortOrder sortType) {
        this.sortType = sortType;
        this.sortField = sortField;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        try {
            Comparable data1 = null;
            try {
                data1 = (Comparable) PropertyUtils.getProperty(o1, sortField);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
                data1 = null;
            }

            Comparable data2 = null;
            try {
                data2 = (Comparable) PropertyUtils.getProperty(o2, sortField);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
                data2 = null;
            }

            return ObjectUtils.compare(data1, data2) * (sortType.equals(SortOrder.ASC) ? 1 : -1);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    public static <T extends Object> void sortList(List<T> list, String sortField, SortOrder sortType) {
        final GenericComparator<T> comparator = new GenericComparator<T>(sortField, sortType);
        Collections.sort(list, comparator);
    }


}
```

This is the test i use :

```
final String sortOrderProperty = "officeName";

List<CompanyRoleProperties> props = myPropertiesMapper.getServiceProviders();
System.err.println("Before DB : " + props);
props.forEach(item -> System.err.println(item));

GenericComparator.sortList(props, sortOrderProperty, SortOrder.ASC);
System.err.println("After DB : " + props);
props.forEach(item -> System.err.println(item));

List<CompanyRoleProperties> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add(new CompanyRoleProperties("KBL European Private Bankers S.A."));
names.add(new CompanyRoleProperties("BDO Audit, S.A."));
System.err.println("Manual Before : " + names);
names.forEach(item -> System.err.println(item));
GenericComparator.sortList(names, sortOrderProperty, SortOrder.ASC);

System.err.println("Manual After : " + names);
names.forEach(item -> System.err.println(item));
```

which gives me the following output :

```
Before DB : [CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=KBL European Private Bankers S.A. ], CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=BDO Audit, S.A.]]
CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=KBL European Private Bankers S.A. ]
CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=BDO Audit, S.A.]


After DB : [CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=KBL European Private Bankers S.A. ], CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=BDO Audit, S.A.]]
CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=KBL European Private Bankers S.A. ]
CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=BDO Audit, S.A.]



Manual Before : [CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=KBL European Private Bankers S.A., ], CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=BDO Audit, S.A., ]]
CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=KBL European Private Bankers S.A., ]
CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=BDO Audit, S.A., ]


Manual After : [CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=BDO Audit, S.A., ], CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=KBL European Private Bankers S.A., ]]
CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=BDO Audit, S.A., ]
CompanyRoleProperties [officeName=KBL European Private Bankers S.A., ]
```

As you can see the list created manually is sorted as expected however it has no effect the DB one. Why would it be the case ?

Comment: The comparator seems to hide a bunch of possible exceptions. If you can't use a debugger, try adding some logging there

Comment: good point but in this situation, no exception is raised. I took the exact same data in both cases

Comment: Still looks like the compare method does something wrong for BDO vs KBL

Comment: my bad i found the problem, i had a typo error in the code that i didn't show in the code snippet above. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. As long as it's solved